# QtGuiのインポートをしようとすると、エラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, macos, qt

こんにちは。
私は、pythonでQtの機能を使いたくて、QtGuiをインポートしようとしました。
しかし、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

PyQt5のインストールは以下のサイトを参考に行いました。
http://hope-is-dream.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/24/143402

色々なサイトで調べてみると上記のようなエラーはライブラリのアーキテクチャの違いで、出てしまうと書かれていました。
そこで、python、QtGuiのアーキテクチャをlipoコマンドで調べてみると、

【python】    
    $ lipo -info /usr/bin/python
    Architectures in the fat file: /usr/bin/python are: x86_64 i386

【QtGui】
    $ lipo -info QtGui.so
    Non-fat file: QtGui.so is architecture: x86_64

それぞれ64bitで構成されていて、違いはなさそうなのですが、なぜエラーが出てしまっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考にされたサイトでは homebrew を使っているので、システムに元から入っている python ではなく `brew` コマンドでインストールされた python を使っていそうな気がします。
`/usr/bin/python` はシステムに入っている python ですが、エラー文で参照しているライブラリのパス `/usr/local/lib/python...` は `brew` でインストールされた python 用のライブラリパスのはずです。

すでに homebrew で python をインストールしていたら、そちら(`/usr/local/bin/python`)を起動して import を試してみて下さい。
もし同じようにエラーが出たら、こちらの python のアーキテクチャを確認してみて下さい。